# If I have a nested multi-level model, how can I find the conditional expectation easily of the middle variable?

Tags: bayesian, multilevel-analysis, hierarchical-bayesian

Suppose I have the following model:

$$
y_i | x_i, V_1 \stackrel{ind}\sim N(x_i, V_2)
$$

$$
x_i| V_1 \stackrel{iid}\sim N(0, V_1)
$$

$$
V_1 \sim Unif(-V_2, \infty)
$$

where the data is $y = (y_1, \ldots, y_n)$, $V_2$ is known to us, and we have that $n \geq 3$.

I would like to find $\mathbb{E}[x_i | y, V_1]$. The only approach I can think of is to first find $p(x_i | y, V_1) = \frac{y_i , x_i, V_1}{p(y, V_1)}$, then use

$$
\mathbb{E}[x_i | y, V_1] = \int x_ip(x_i | y, V_1) dx_i
$$

To obtain $p(y, V_1)$, it is marginalized out from:

$$
p(y, V_1) = \int p(y, x_i, V_1)dx_i
$$

The indicator variable on the $V_1$ prior will cancel, but this is a nightmare to go this route. Does anyone have any other ideas how to attack this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be easier to first write the posterior distribution for both $(x_i, V_1)$

$$p(x_i, V_1|y) \propto p(y|x_i,V_1)p(x_i|V_1)p(V_1).$$

Note how I used the proportionality sign that absorbed $p(y)$ from the denominator. The reason this can be done is that $p(y)$ is a constant for $x_i, V_1|y$. Once you have this written out (no need to simplify is completely), find

$$p(x_i|V_1,y) = \dfrac{p(x_i, V_1|y)}{p(V_1|y)} \propto p(x_i,V_1|y). $$

Using the same trick again, you can absorb $V_1$ which is now a constant. Your hope in doing all this is that once you have absorbed all constants, $p(x_i|V_1,y)$ will be proportional to a kernel that you can identify as a known distribution, and hence know the distribution of $x_i|V_1,y$.

As an example (this is not related to your original problem), if for some hierarchical setup of $z, w, y$ I obtain 
$$p(z|w, y) \propto z^{3y}e^{-wz} $$

Then I know $z|w, y \sim Gamma(3y+1, w)$ and the mean for this is $(3y+1)/w)$.

Comment: Could I ask how the form of $V_1 \sim Unif(-V_2, \infty)$ would be written in density form? Is it the indicator random variable, $1_{[-V_2, \infty)}$ or would it be $\frac{1}{\infty + V_2}$? Thanks!

Comment: The density for $V_1 \sim Unif(-V_2, \infty)$ will be $\pi(V_1) \propto 1_{[-V_2, \infty]}$. This is an improper prior.

Comment: This might be a dumb question, but I am normally used to writing a uniform prior for something like $X \sim Unif(0, \theta)$ as $\pi(\theta) = \frac{1}{\theta}1_{(0,\theta)}$. Do you know know why I can drop the $\frac{1}{\theta}$ to obtain the form you have? thanks

Comment: Notice how I wrote $\propto$ and not $=$. This is because the exact density would look like $\frac{1}{\infty + V_2} 1_{[-V_2, \infty]}$, but $\frac{1}{\infty + V_2}$ is undefined, so that makes no sense. Which is why we ignore that part and just use the indicator, and instead of equality, use proportionality.

Comment: Thanks! Just one more thing, is the reason I can treat $V_1$ because it is known in the model? I am just not sure why we took $p(x_i, V_1|y) \propto p(x_i|V_1)p(V_1).$ instead of $p(x_i, V_1|y) \propto p(x_i, V_1,y) \propto p(y |x_i, V_1)p(x_i|V_1)p(V_1)$, since it seems in the latter we can incorporate the first model in as well.

Comment: @user1398057 oops, sorry. There was a huge typo there and I had the posterior wrong. I have fixed it now. Thanks!